# Ordercloud Migration to new Sandbox

Tags: migration, sitecore, backup, sandbox, ordercloud

we have some issues in current US West sandbox , hence would have to move our store/site and full code base with data into a new Ordercloud Sandbox , any inputs/process/ steps would be really helpful.

Thanks
Vinay

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a new marketplace in another region and manually transfer the data. We have no tools or resources available to facilitate such a transfer.